# .Net WebAPI Post method is not working from Angular2 service

Tags: angular, post, asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-405

I am newbie in Angular 2. I am sending form data from angular 2 to webapi but it is not working.
**WebAPI:**

```
public class FetchDataController : ApiController
    {

        [HttpGet]
        public IList<Student> ListOfStudents()
        {
            AppRepository objapp = new AppRepository();
            IList<Student> objData = null;
            objData = objapp.getStudent();
            return objData;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("PostStudent")]
        public JsonResult<Boolean> PostStudent(Student value)
        {
            // Append text to an existing file named "WriteLines.txt".
            string data = "ID: " + value.Id + ", FirstName: " + value.FirstName + ",LastName: " + value.LastName + ",Salary: " + value.salary;
            using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~")+ "/TestVD/WriteLines.txt", true))
            {
                outputFile.WriteLine(data);
            }
            return Json(true);
        }

    }
```

My WebAPIConfig.js is as follows. I have added CORS handling in here as well as Webconfig file:

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost", "*", "*");
              config.EnableCors(cors);

            // Web API configuration and services
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));
            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ListOfStudents",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "FetchData", action = "ListOfStudents", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
               name: "PostStudent",
               routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
               defaults: new { controller = "FetchData", action = "PostStudent", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Now, From Angular 2, I am able to show data using List of student webAPI method but while posting I am getting "405 (Method Not Allowed)" from my WEBAPI url.
I am gettling below response from WEBAPI post method.

```
ok
:
false
status
:
405
statusText
:
"Method Not Allowed"
type
:
2
url
:
"http://localhost/TestWebService/api/FetchData/"
_body
:
"{"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'."}"
```

My Angular 2 service code is as follows

```
@Injectable()
export class RssService {
private studentUrl = "http://localhost/TestWebService/api/FetchData/";
    constructor(private http: Http) {   }
    getStudentList() {
        return this.http.get(this.studentUrl)
            .map(res => <Student[]>res.json())
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
    private handleError(error: Response) {
        console.error(error);
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
    }
    postStudent(model: any): Observable<any> {
        let body = JSON.stringify(model);
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        console.log('add Student start : ' + body);
        return this.http.post(this.studentUrl , body, options)
            .map((response: Response) => <any>response.json())
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
}
```

Could you please help me...

Answer (score 0):

You have a routing attribute `[Route("PostStudent")]` on your PostStudent method.

Because of it, URL for this action is not `http://localhost/TestWebService/api/FetchData/`, but `http://localhost/TestWebService/PostStudent`.

To use URL `http://localhost/TestWebService/api/FetchData/` just remove this `Route` attribute.

If you still want to use specific Route for `PostStudent` action and access it via `http://localhost/TestWebService/api/FetchData/PostStudent`, add also `RoutePrefix` attribute on your controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/FetchData")]
public class FetchDataController : ApiController
```

Check this article for mode details: [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it due to System.Net and System.Web namespace. This [link](https://dontpaniclabs.com/blog/post/2013/01/23/That-Pesky-Requested-Resource-Does-Not-Support-HTTP-Method-POST-Error-When-Using-MVC-Web-API/) help me a lot.